# Info on non published packages

Tags: php, composer-php

How would I list the information for a local package?

Trying to run something like this while in a directory that contains a composer.json (`composer info {vendor/package}`)

I would like to know what my package's info would display without publishing it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be this but it does not show all the information

`composer show --self`